# What is syndication?

Tags: terminology

I was looking at broadcast schedules trying to figure out when a season of a show I like would enter syndication, and I realized that I wasn't really even sure what syndication was.

So, what is syndication, and what determines when/if a show will be offered in syndication?

Answer (score 5):

Syndication is quite simply the process of renting an existing (already filmed) TV show to a network and it typically falls into one of two categories:

1. An existing show which has reached a number of episodes, usually [100](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/100_episodes), is rented to other channels who can then air reruns of it. This is sometimes called **Off-network syndication** and examples would include *any foreign television show which airs in other countries*.
2. A new show is made by a production company with the intention to sell it to channels later. This is typically called **[First-run syndication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broadcast_syndication#First-run_syndication_in_the_U.S.)**, some examples include:

   - [Star Trek: The Next Generation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek:_The_Next_Generation)
   - [Police Academy: The Series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Police_Academy:_The_Series)
   - [ThunderCats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ThunderCats_%281985_TV_series%29)
   - [Mortal Kombat: Konquest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mortal_Kombat:_Konquest)

[Wikipedia also mentions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broadcast_syndication#Types_of_syndication) a third type of syndication which appears to be unique (or at least most common) to the USA called **Public broadcasting syndication** in which a larger network will allow a public broadcasting (non-profit TV) network, such as [PBS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBS) in the US, to rent a television show for re-broadcast. Some examples include:

- [Globe Trekker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globe_Trekker) (Originally [Channel 4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Channel_4))
- [Mr. Bean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mr._Bean) (Originally [ITV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ITV_%28TV_network%29))
- [The Two Ronnies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Two_Ronnies) (Originally [BBC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BBC))

---

In additions to sources linked above, additional information from:

- [Category: First-run syndicated television programs in the United States](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Category:First-run_syndicated_television_programs_in_the_United_States) on Wikipedia
- [List of programs broadcast by PBS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_programs_broadcast_by_PBS) on Wikipedia